# How to move the position of month and year dropdowns to a different month

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following options for jQuery UI DatePicker which displays previous/current/next months:

```
datepicker_options = {
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    showOtherMonths: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    showCurrentAtPos: 1,
    changeYear: true,
}
```

[image]

How would I move the month and date drop downs from the previous to the current month?

Comment: You mean, you want to change the Drop Down enablement for the middle calendar than the left one?

Comment: Yes, for the example image I'd like for October to display the drop downs.

Comment: Ah, Fish, that's not gonna happen with the current way the datepicker plugin is created. You might need to redo the `inst.yearshtml` for that. `:)` See my answer.

Comment: Oh well, thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Sorry mate. I went through the whole source code, but to find nothing. Maybe I can try to switch the select from the first one to the other, but not sure how it's going to affect the datepicker itself... Might screw up. If you want, I can try it. But why don't you go with something like [Date Range Picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#config), which provides more options? Hint: `showDropdowns`.

Comment: Lemme know I might take this up as a challenge for this weekend and try it out... `:)`

Comment: I think I'll leave it as it is. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **No!**

Looking at the source code for [`jquery-ui/datepicker.js`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/widgets/datepicker.js) at [Line #1841](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/widgets/datepicker.js#L1841), it seems that you will be only able to enable the Select Month and Year dropdowns for the first ever calendar and not anywhere else. You might need to change the code here to make it work for you, showing it in the middle, if you need.

```
_generateMonthYearHeader: function( inst, drawMonth, drawYear, minDate, maxDate,
                                     secondary, monthNames, monthNamesShort ) {

  var inMinYear, inMaxYear, month, years, thisYear, determineYear, year, endYear,
      changeMonth = this._get( inst, "changeMonth" ),
      changeYear = this._get( inst, "changeYear" ),
      showMonthAfterYear = this._get( inst, "showMonthAfterYear" ),
      html = "<div class='ui-datepicker-title'>",
      monthHtml = "";

  // Month selection
  if ( secondary || !changeMonth ) {
    monthHtml += "<span class='ui-datepicker-month'>" + monthNames[ drawMonth ] + "</span>";
  } else {
    inMinYear = ( minDate && minDate.getFullYear() === drawYear );
    inMaxYear = ( maxDate && maxDate.getFullYear() === drawYear );
    monthHtml += "<select class='ui-datepicker-month' data-handler='selectMonth' data-event='change'>";
    for ( month = 0; month < 12; month++ ) {
      if ( ( !inMinYear || month >= minDate.getMonth() ) && ( !inMaxYear || month <= maxDate.getMonth() ) ) {
        monthHtml += "<option value='" + month + "'" +
          ( month === drawMonth ? " selected='selected'" : "" ) +
          ">" + monthNamesShort[ month ] + "</option>";
      }
    }
    monthHtml += "</select>";
  }

  if ( !showMonthAfterYear ) {
    html += monthHtml + ( secondary || !( changeMonth && changeYear ) ? "&#xa0;" : "" );
  }

  // Year selection
  if ( !inst.yearshtml ) {
    inst.yearshtml = "";
    if ( secondary || !changeYear ) {
      html += "<span class='ui-datepicker-year'>" + drawYear + "</span>";
    } else {

      // determine range of years to display
      years = this._get( inst, "yearRange" ).split( ":" );
      thisYear = new Date().getFullYear();
      determineYear = function( value ) {
        var year = ( value.match( /c[+\-].*/ ) ? drawYear + parseInt( value.substring( 1 ), 10 ) :
                    ( value.match( /[+\-].*/ ) ? thisYear + parseInt( value, 10 ) :
                     parseInt( value, 10 ) ) );
        return ( isNaN( year ) ? thisYear : year );
      };
      year = determineYear( years[ 0 ] );
      endYear = Math.max( year, determineYear( years[ 1 ] || "" ) );
      year = ( minDate ? Math.max( year, minDate.getFullYear() ) : year );
      endYear = ( maxDate ? Math.min( endYear, maxDate.getFullYear() ) : endYear );
      inst.yearshtml += "<select class='ui-datepicker-year' data-handler='selectYear' data-event='change'>";
      for ( ; year <= endYear; year++ ) {
        inst.yearshtml += "<option value='" + year + "'" +
          ( year === drawYear ? " selected='selected'" : "" ) +
          ">" + year + "</option>";
      }
      inst.yearshtml += "</select>";

      html += inst.yearshtml;
      inst.yearshtml = null;
    }
  }

  html += this._get( inst, "yearSuffix" );
  if ( showMonthAfterYear ) {
    html += ( secondary || !( changeMonth && changeYear ) ? "&#xa0;" : "" ) + monthHtml;
  }
  html += "</div>"; // Close datepicker_header
  return html;
},
```

You would need to find out what the rest of `html` variable looks like and you need to edit it. But editing the plugin is not a good idea as it might get updated at a later time and you might need to keep up with it.